# How to use SSL sockets on client

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I am currently working on a project using SSL sockets to communicate, and I was wondering how the client accesses the SSL certificate. Keep in mind that I am using a java server, and the client will be possibly on different hardware platforms eg Ios or android. How do I achieve SSL authentication without giving out the certificate to all platforms?

Comment: which certificate? The one that certifies the server is legit? That one needs to be present everywhere (or verifiable through other present certificates)

Comment: How should I access it from the client then?

Comment: Why do you want access to it? The server will send it's certificate (see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ), the client will (on it's own, internally in `SSLSocket`) checks against known certificates that the server certificate is legit. The client needs to know trusted certificates before connecting to the server, so you have to ship the certificate with every platform when it's a self-signed one. You don't have to do that when it's an "official" certifcate because the platforms already have all the "official" root certificates.

Comment: oops the link was https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10660_.htm